# Elixir/erlang server with http2 and SNI support

Tags: erlang, elixir, cowboy

I once wrote a small reverse-proxy in node.js that was capable of routing any request of any (defined) domain to it's according endpoints in a DMZ with several servers.

I currently want to rewrite that whole thing on an Erlang/Elixir basis and started with the webframework Phoenix. Phenix already supports http2 very well, but the underlying cowboy server does not support SNI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

So does anyone have experience or ever did implement SNI with http2 with Erlang, and has a hint for that if there is something available or a starting point or if that would itself start a whole new project?

Comment: I never experimented with it, but _Ranch_, which is a socket acceptor pool behind _Cowboy_, seems to [support SNI](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/ranch/2.0/manual/ranch_ssl/) starting with [v2.0](https://github.com/ninenines/ranch/blob/5c530ba58d142507f4c454bdfba00392d02af3ee/test/handshake_protocol.erl#L12-L23).

Comment: thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin, that's a good hint. Well, I think I have to go deeper into that erlang worlds :)